# find y(0.1) given diffrential equation: $y''+xy'+y=0$ with initial conditions $y(0)=1$ & $y'(0)=0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, differential

Given that the second order differential equation: 
$$y''+xy'+y=0$$
with initial conditions: $y(0)=1$ & $y'(0)=0$

Find out the value of $y(0.1)$

My try:
$$\int y''+\int xy'+\int y=\int 0$$
$$y'+x y+yx=C_1$$
$$y'+2x y=C_1$$
$$\int y'+2y \int x=\int C_1$$
$$y+2y\cdot \frac{x^2}{2}=C_1x+C_2$$
$$y+x^2y=C_1x+C_2$$
$$y=\frac{C_1x+C_2}{1+x^2}$$
setting x=0, y=1
$$1=\frac{C_1\cdot 0+C_2}{1+0^2}\iff  C_2=1$$
setting $x=0$ & $y'=0$,
$$0+2(0) (1)=C_1\iff C_1=0$$
$$y=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$
setting $x=0.1$
$$y(0.1)=\frac{1}{1+0.1^2}=0.99$$
But my teacher suggests the correct answer: $exp(-1/200). But I don't know where I am wrong. Someone please help me to get correct answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
y''+xy'+y=0
&\iff (y'+xy)'=0\\
&\iff y'+xy=C_1\\
&\iff \exp{(x^2/2)}y'+x\exp{(x^2/2)}y=C_1\exp{(x^2/2)}\\
&\iff (\exp{(x^2/2)}y)'=C_1\exp{(x^2/2)}\\
&\iff \exp{(x^2/2)}y=C_2\text{erfi}{(x/\sqrt{2})}+C_3\\
&\iff y=(C_2\text{erfi}{(x/\sqrt{2})}+C_3)\exp{(-x^2/2)}\\
\end{align}
Given the initial conditions we get
$$y=\exp{(-x^2/2)}$$
and hence
$$y(0.1)=\exp{(-0.005)}$$